# Rocket Nose Cone Design ,Ogives,technical drawings are not understood

Tags: solidworks, technical-drawing, rocketry

I'm trying to draw a rocket nose cone. Notice the red marked at the bottom left of technical drawing. I couldn't figure out what the diameters 26.870 AND 59.732 mean. I drew endless lines vertically to these points and tried to draw circles at these values, but I couldn't make sense of it.Any help?
high resolution techincal drawing in this link
https://i.imgur.com/b483Iqd.jpeg

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The original drawing is illegible. Can you post one with a decent resolution?

Comment: of course https://i.imgur.com/b483Iqd.jpeg you have to wait a little bit cause of high resolution

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the new image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be drawn if the segments are not tangential to each other.

[image]

If you want tangential transition, you can define it just between the spherical cap and second segment if the cap is not hemisphere (seems nicer), but the second transition between second and third segment cannot be tangential, so the transition points have to be defined by diameters at distances from the table.
[image]